# Is there a way to conditionally determine what a component is binding to in Blazor?

Tags: data-binding, blazor

For background, for each of my forms they bind to one of two objects: either InsertParameters or UpdateParameters depending on if you're doing an insert or an update. The forms are identical for both inserts and updates so I'd like them to handle both. I need to achieve two-way binding.

I don't want to have to duplicate the components for both updating and inserting.

I'd like to be able to do something like this, checking in the component binding what to bind to:

`<InputDate @bind-Value=@(updateParams is not null ? updateParams.Date : insertParams.Date) />`

Currently, I'm able to achieve this through something like this:

```
<InputDate Value=@(updateParams is not null ? updateParams.Date : insertParams.Date)
           ValueChanged=@((x) => HandleValueChanged(x, nameof(CaseActivity.Date)) />
```

HandleValueChanged:

```
private void HandleValueChanged(object? value, string propertyName)
{
    if (value == null) return;

    if (updateParams != null)
    {
        PropertySetter.SetPropertyValue(updateParams, propertyName, value);
    }
    else
    {
        PropertySetter.SetPropertyValue(insertParams!, propertyName, value);
    }
}
```

PropertySetter:

```
public static void SetPropertyValue<T>(T obj, string propertyName, object? value)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(obj));
    }

    if (propertyName == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(propertyName));
    }

    Type objectType = typeof(T);
    PropertyInfo? property = objectType.GetProperty(propertyName);

    if (property == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"Property '{propertyName}' not found on type '{objectType.FullName}'.");
    }

    if (!property.CanWrite)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"Property '{propertyName}' on type '{objectType.FullName}' does not have a public setter.");
    }

    property.SetValue(obj, value);
}
```

While this works, I just feel there must be a better way to achieve this that's more built in but my searches haven't yielded any success.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: An alternative approach would be to have a stateful Edit Context object that represents your data object .  The state being Create/Update/Delete.  Your data pipeline creates a new data object from the Edit Context and make the appropriate create/update/delete decision on how to apply the command to the data store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have control over the params types:

```
interface IHaveDate { DateTime Date { get; set; } }

class InsertParams : IHaveDate { ... }
class UpdateParams : IHaveDate { ... }
```

and then use it like

```
<InputDate @bind-Value="@(updateParams as IHaveDate ?? insertParams).Date" />
```

Comment: So I could create an interface with all of the shared fields between the InsertParams and UpdateParams, then use as directed above?

Comment: Yes, of course. Or a base-class.

Comment: Thank you, I knew there was a simple solution I was missing.

Comment: I have updated the using code a little.